# Dialogflow response is not stable, it is keep on changing? How to get stable results from dialogflow in response?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using Google DialogFlow for my application for identifying the text response in parsing the resume. Every time the response keeps on changing.
1 week back I trained a string and get the proper response but today while checking the same string the response is not coming proper, it is not taking a few of the fields.
Also for date identification, the problem is the very similar dialog flow after training the string properly keep on varying the response.
If I try the same string 5 times all the time's results are not same it keep on changing like -
This is the string i trained-

"SSCE(CBSE) from L.B.S. Public School, Pratap Nagar,Jaipur(2013-2014) with aggregate 69.20%."

below are the screenshots attached of varying response-

[response I am getting first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGkkD.png)

[response I am getting second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es8Eb.png)

Answer (score 2):

Dialogflow is not a parser - the training phrases you give it aren't strings that will be matched, they help set the pattern for a Natural Language Understanding (NLU) system. So they're tuned for how people naturally speak or type.

It is also somewhat unusual to have multiple parameters with the same name. I can easily see how the system would ignore a second occurrence when done this way. (Although you may try setting up those parameters as lists.)

Comment: I didn't mean it is a parser, but my point is why dialogflow is not giving the same result when the same sentence is passed the second time?